# Unable to do formating for itemplate in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have below itemtemplate in gridview where I need to show `-`stead of null values.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPrice" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Price") %>' Font-Underline="true" 
     OnCommand="lnkbtnPrice_Click" ForeColor="Black" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:C2}") %>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

I also tried changes the text format like below and still underlines are appearing for null values.

```
Text='<%#(Eval("Price") == DBNull.Value ? "-" : Eval("Price", "{0:C2}"))%>'
```

Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: what's the error, the condition seems to be working fine,

Comment: "underlines are appearing for null values"  Sounds like that's what you want..?